# Set value of last ID before query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to set the value of a variable to the last ID inserted in the DB *before* inserting my query.

Currently I've got the following code:

```
// Construct
public function __construct($content, $emotion, $conn)
{
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->emotion = $emotion;
    $this->post = 
        "<div id=\'post\'>
            <div id=\'postContent\'>
                <p><b>I\'m $this->emotion because</b> $this->Id $this->content<span class=\'emot\'id=\'$this->emotion\'></span></p>
            </div>
            <div id=\'postInfo\'>
                <span class=\'postRelate\' title=\'Click to relate +1\'><p><b>relate</b> (0)</p></span>
                <span class=\'postSubmitted\'><p>submitted X minutes ago</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>";     
}

// Confirm booking (update database) function
public function insert_userPost($conn) 
{
    if($this->content != "")
    {   
        // SQL INSERT command
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO userPost (content, submitted, emotion)
                 VALUES ('$this->post', NOW(), '$this->emotion')");
        $this->Id = $conn->insert_id;
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            header('Location: feed.php?filter=all&page=1');
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: post.php');
    }
}
```

In the construct I'm setting the variable $post to a div containing containing the $this->Id variable.

Down at the insert_userPost() function I'm inserting a query containing $this->post and another setting the Id to the last ID inserted into the database. I know that it's successfully getting the ID from the database. However, as I'm clearly getting the value for Id *before* the insert it's not correctly appearing on $post after the insert.

Comment: You can not get the database's internal id until it is actually inserted into the database... You will probably get an id from a previous inserted row!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't word it great. My question is more about ways in which I can achieve the same goal. Is there nothing can I do? I understand that I'd be able to get the highest ID from the DB and +1 but I can imagine this would lead to some pretty nasty problems.

Comment: @LiamMacmillan: Yeah it would.. There is no proper way to get the last inserted ID apart from actually inserting the last row and retrieving its ID.

Comment: @D4V1D Basically, I need to be able to select the post somehow and currently it has no ID attached to it, so it's impossible to do (I think).

Comment: @LiamMacmillan: Where do you want to select it from? It is not in the DB yet.

Comment: Basically, the DIV in $post is displayed on a feed alongside many others. On the feed I want to be able to identify a post by it's ID, however, currently there's no way to do that. In the database the ID is there, but once it's posted it doesn't have anything to do with the DB.

Comment: Add a column posted. In the construct, add the post to the database to get an ID. Set posted=false and submitted to NOW(). In insert_userPost, you set posted=true, and delete rows with posted=false WHERE submitted is older than one day...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and you can fetch ->insert_id all you want. but until you actually perform the insert, it's just doing to be a boolean false/null value.

Comment: @HasseBjörk Good idea, I'll try that!

Comment: @MarcB I know, I'm going to change it after I get ID from DB :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not get an ID from the database, unless you really insert a row. It is hard to predict what ID MySQL uses.

You have to add the post in the construct to get an ID for reference. You could set a new column in the database to `posted=false` and `submitted=NOW()`.

IN `insert_userPost()` you set `posted=true` and delete all rows with `posted=false WHERE submitted<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`.

Another solution is to store everything temporarily in a session variable without ID, and store/fetch changes from the session. When it is posted you add it to the database!